# Position absolute element causing overlap

Tags: html, css

Here's the link structure of the page:

```
    <div>
    <h2><a href="#" target="_blank"  class="button one">Digital Marketing </a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"  class="button one">Video Production </a> 
        <a href="#" target="_blank"  class="button one">Graphics Design </a> 
    </h2></div>
```

And the css:

```
    .button{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
                    padding: 10px;
                    margin: 10px 20px 30px 0 !important;
}
                    
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .button {
    display:block;
      z-index:above;
  }
}
```

It works as intended on a screen bigger than 800px. However on my mobile device, the last link becomes unclickable as it gets overlapped with the next element on the page.

Is this an issue of CSS position attribute? How can I fix this?

Comment: If you remove the `position: absolute` from the first section it works, no idea why it has that style. I removed that and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there are no `position:absolute`s, you can add a margin to the elements. This pushes other elements away from itself, by a given distance.

Comment: I don't see any position:absolute in the CSS. Plus I tried adding `margin: 1% auto;` but the third link is still unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

I would try giving the top and bottom margin a value in % instead of px, then it can work out its own space and you'll avoid overlapping.

Maybe experiment a bit like so:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .button {
    display:block;

    margin: 1% auto;
  }
```

And also, I don't know if you need the z-index for something you have on the page already, but you're gonna need to give it an actual value for it to work:

z-index syntax: auto|number|initial|inherit;

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on z-index. I tried adding `margin: 1% auto;` but the third link is still unclickable. Please help.

Comment: i would install pesticide in that case and try to figure things out with the borders